# How do I update the dropdown list to the order metadata? Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I override the `Woocommerce checkout page` to make a dropdown list on it. And I want to save the meta data of the dropdown list to the `wp_postmeta`.

I am trying to use these code, but it doesn't work. (form-checkout)

Making the downdrop list, and get the admin name.

```
<select class = "drop-down-list" name = "drop-down-list"   >

            <!-- Search the administrator user -->
            <?php 

                $args = array (
                        'role' => 'administrator',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'display_name',
                        'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                                        'value'   => $search_term,
                                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'key'     => 'last_name',
                                        'value'   => $search_term,
                                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'key' => 'description',
                                        'value' => $search_term ,
                                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                        )
                );
                    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

                    // Get the results
                    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

                    // Check for results
                    if (!empty($authors)) {

                        // loop through each author
                        foreach ($authors as $author)
                        {
                            // get all the user's data
                            $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
                            echo '<option value =\'' . $author_info->display_name . '\'>' . $author_info->display_name . '</option>';
                        }

                    } else {
                        echo 'No authors found';
                    }

            ?>
            </select>
```

Update the `wp_postmeta` when click the place order button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc' );

        function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc() {
            global $woocommerce, $post;
            $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

            //to escape # from order id

            $order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['drop-down-list'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $order_id, 'drop-down-list', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['drop-down-list'] ) );

            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The first code you provided where you display a list of all admins in what file did u place that code? It should be placed between the form tag in the `form-checkout.php` located in your theme folder under `woocommerce/checkout` or in the plugin `templates/checkout`

Comment: Those codes are in the same file `woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

Comment: Yes but is the `<select>` between the `<form>` tag?

Comment: No..I only put it in `<div>`

Comment: Then make sure the value is submitted via the `<form>` but adding it to the `form-checkout.php` right after the `<form>` line and it should work